# error while making store procedure

Tags: .net

```
            int SpParam = 0;
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "sp_SelectCountry";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_id,@country_name",SpParam);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dtCountry);
            con.Close();
```

showing error .. liking while Sp_SelectCountry Hav No Paramerter like dat .. Pls Help Guys ..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might need to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and this: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to establish two input parameters with a single statement, which is not possible.  Instead break the statement into multiple statements, one for each parameter, thusly:

```
...
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_id", countryId);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_name", contryName);
...
```

where countryId and countryName are local variables of the proper type that are initialized to the values you wish to use in the call to the stored procedure.

Comment: it Still Showing The The Same Error .. Procedure sp_SelectCountry has no parameters and arguments were supplied.   
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_id",SpParam);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@country_name", SpParam);

Comment: In that case, adding parameters to the `Parameters` collection of the `Command` object you're using to execute the query is a mistake. Do you have the ability see the source code for the stored procedure, or perhaps some documentation about it?  Without an idea of the input and/or output parameters that the stored procedure expects, then it will be difficult to execute it.